# Can't read_excel with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, attributeerror

I am learning pandas lib. in Python3, but i have a big problem. When i use command to read_excel i get an error.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\PythonProjects\stocks.xlsx',sheetname=0)
```

The error looks like this:

```
C:\Users\Kuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:118: FutureWarning: The `sheetname` keyword is deprecated, use `sheet_name` instead
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/MyPythonProjects/urlib.py", line 4, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\MyPythonProjects\NewL\stocksa.xlsx',sheetname=0 )
  File "C:\Users\Kuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 230, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\Kuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 294, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(self._io)
  File "C:\Users\Kuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 141, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "C:\Users\Kuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 808, in open_workbook_2007_xml
    x12book.process_stream(zflo, 'Workbook')
  File "C:\Users\Kuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 265, in process_stream
    meth(self, elem)
  File "C:\Users\Kuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 392, in do_sheet
    sheet = Sheet(bk, position=None, name=name, number=sheetx)
  File "C:\Users\Kuba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 326, in __init__
    self.extract_formulas = book.extract_formulas
AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'extract_formulas'
```

I don't know how to fix it. I 've tried to reinstall pandas, xlrd and still i get the same error. Can you give me an advice how to repair that problem.

Comment: Are you running latest versions as well?

Comment: is that the sheetname? 0? and use `sheet_name` not `sheetname`

Comment: I have tried with sheet_name

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you do

```
pd.ExcelFile(filename)
```

If that throws the same error, then it might due to the version of `xlrd`. I couldn't find `extract_formula` from `xlrd`'s `Book` object from their latest release. [[source]](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd/book.py)

Comment: DId you look at the error code ? *AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'extract_formulas'*

Answer (score 0):

try installing the

> xlrd version '0.9.4'

Worked for me

Answer (score -1):

just add at the beginning of your program:

```js
import xlrd
```

> in case it's not found, > pip install xlrd