# AttributeError: 'Book' Object has no attribute 'extract formulas'

Tags: python, pandas, import, xlsx

I've installed Python 3.7

I am using Pandas to import an Excel Workbook and it gives me an error

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(r'C\:Users\bobandtom\PycharmProjects\Downtown\identity_tape.xlsx ')
```

And I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'extract_formulas'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49325837/cant-read-excel-with-pandas

Comment: Yes, looks close, unfortunately those answers did resolve the issue.